Consulta mysqli no retorna resultados
Tengo un sistema para manejo de préstamos, ya tengo el listado, pero ahora necesito hacer una búsqueda con mysqli, integrando un paginador. La misma es sobre dos tablas, préstamos y tipos de préstamo. Mi problema es que siempre me retorna "sin registros". Este es mi código:
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("configuracion/dbConfig.php");
    include("Pagination.class.php");
    
    
      if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    
        var_dump($_POST['page']);
        
        
        
      $baseURL = 'getPrestamos.php';
      $offset = !empty($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:0;
      $limit = 15;
      
        
        $whereSQL = "WHERE a.tipoID = b.tipoID";
        
        if(!empty($_POST['keywords']))
        {
            $whereSQL = $whereSQL." AND (a.numero LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' || a.referencia LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' || a.nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' || a.socioID LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' || a.rnc LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' || a.prestamoID LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%') ";
        }
    
        if(!empty($_POST['agencia']))
        {
            $whereSQL = $whereSQL." AND a.agenciaID LIKE '%".$_POST['agencia']."%' ";
        }
    
        $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowNum FROM co_prestamos a,co_prestamos_tipos b ".$whereSQL);
             
        $result  = $query->fetch_assoc();
        
        $rowCount= $result['rowNum'];
      
     
        $pagConfig = array(
            'baseURL' => $baseURL,
            'totalRows' => $rowCount,
            'perPage' => $limit,
        'currentPage' => $offset,
        'contentDiv' => 'dataContainer',
        'link_func' => 'searchFilter'
        );
        $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);
    
        // Fetch records based on the offset and limit
        $query = $db->query(" SELECT a.*, b.nombre AS concepto
             FROM co_prestamos a, co_prestamos_tipos b $whereSQL ORDER BY a.prestamoID DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit");
    ?>
        
            <?php
            if($query->num_rows > 0){?>
             <table class="table table-hover attendance-table">
                <thead style="background: #E8E8E8; border-style: solid; border-color: gray; border-radius: 20px;">
                   <tr>
                      <th><i class="fa-light fa-bars"></i></th>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Socio</th>
                      <th>Cedula</th>
                      <th>Concepto</th>
                      <th>Plazo</th>
                      <th>Inicio</th>
                      <th>Termino</th>
                      <th>Cuota</th>
                      <th>Capital</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
          <?php
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                    $offset++
            ?>
    <tr>
                      <td>
                         <a href="prestamosADPanel.php?prestamoID='.$row["prestamoID"].'&socioID='.$row["socioID"].'">
                            <span class="text-muted"></span>
                            <i class="fa-light fa-eye"></i>
                         </a>
                      </td>   
                            <td><?= $row["prestamoID"];?></td>
                            <td><?= $row["nombre"];?></td>
                            <td><?= substr($row["rnc"],0,3)."-".substr($row["rnc"],3,7)."-".substr($row["rnc"],-1); ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row["concepto"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row["cuotas"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row["inicio"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row["termino"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?= number_format($row['cuota'], 2); ?></td>
                            <td><?= number_format($row['capital'], 2); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                        }
            
            }else{
                echo '<tr><td><h2 style="text-align:center;color:#092B69;">No hay registros</h2></td></tr>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
      
    <?php
    }
    
    
    
    ?>


Ya sea que intente navegar a las siguientes páginas o cuando intento filtrar por agencia o por un campo de texto libre, siempre me devuelve "sin registros", tal parece que el problema está en esta línea: $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowNum FROM co_prestamos a,co_prestamos_tipos b ".$whereSQL);, pero no sé como resolverlo.
Cualquier comentario será de mucha ayuda.
Gracias.

Prueba a mostrar la consulta que generas e introdúcela en un cliente MySQL, a ver si te devuelve datos. También puedes probar a meter el $db-> query dentro de un try/Catch y ver si te da error la construcción de tu consulta

Sin entrar al hecho que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL,  estás construyendo una cláusula where ignorando las reglas del lenguaje SQL. Esto provoca que ningún registro cumpla con la condición.

Lo primero que resaltaría es que estás usando la sintaxis sin usar la cláusula join, que se introdujo en el estándar hace nada más y nada menos que 32 años, en 1992. Esto, si bien funciona, crea primero una mayor complejidad en la cláusula where, que mezcla las condiciones para unir las tablas con las condiciones de filtrado y, por tanto, hace el código más difícil de leer y de mantener. Sugiero que primero cambies eso, en lugar de:
select *
  from tabla1 a, tabla2 b
 where a.campo = b.campo
   and otras condiciones

Escribe la consulta así:
select *
  from tabla1 a 
       inner join tabla2 b on b.campo = a.campo
 where solo condiciones de filtrado

Si no estás acostumbrado a esta sintaxis, al principio te parecerá algo extraña, pero una vez te vayas acostumbrando, se te harán mucho más fáciles de escribir, leer y mantener.

Una vez hecho este cambio, recuerda que el operador lógico or en SQL es la palabra or misma, y no la doble barra (supongo que estás tratándola de usar como OR, quzás porque tu pasado esté relacionado con el lenguaje C o lenguajes que derivan de su sintaxis.
En SQL, el operador || existe, y sirva para concatenar cadenas, en los motores que lo soportan, como mySQL.
A mi manera de ver, la sentencia resultante, si _POST['keywords'] vale "XX", sería algo como:
select ...
  from ...
 where ...
   AND (a.numero LIKE '%XX%' || a.referencia LIKE '%XX%' || a.nombre LIKE '%XX%' || a.socioID LIKE '%XX%' || a.rnc LIKE '%XX%' || a.prestamoID LIKE '%XX%')

Y esto tendría que dar un error de sintaxis, pero mySQL es poco formal en estas cosas y, según parece, está haciendo alguna concatenación, que no me imagino que es...
Como sea, la sentencia válida, ya metiendo todas las conidiciones tendría que tener la forma:
select ...
  from tabla1 a
       inner join tabla2 b on b.campo = a.campo 
 where (    a.numero LIKE '%XX%' 
         or a.referencia LIKE '%XX%' 
         or a.nombre LIKE '%XX%' 
         or a.socioID LIKE '%XX%' 
         or a.rnc LIKE '%XX%' 
         or a.prestamoID LIKE '%XX%'
        )
   and a.agencia like '%MiAgencia%'




Buen día,primero gracias por tu respuesta,ahora,ya hice los cambios que sugieres pero sigue sin darme resultados

Si esta consulta no da resultados, diría que no hay ningún resultado entonces. A menos que no sea la consulta como la sugerí. Podrías preparar un fiddle con un ejemplo?

Ya lo resolví,resulta que era un conflicto con codificación utf8 mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
